# How to delete a remote branch after wrong push

Tags: git

I'm new with git and I made a typo mistake in the remote branch name during my push.

```
git push remote/branch_with_typo_mistake.
```

Then a new branch was created on the remote server.

How can i **completely** remove this new non-wanted branch from the server ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `git push remote :branch_with_typo_mistake`.
Note the colon before the branch name.

Comment: After that, it's completely removed ? nobody can see this branch ?

Comment: You can rename your local branch also: `git branch -m branch_with_typo_mistake branch_without_typo`